# Looking for a site that shows major european train routes and their speed/duration

Tags: trains, online-resources, europe, maps

I'm trying to plan a bit of a European tour by train visiting a few locations on the way. It's hard to see a good overview of the major routes (and their speeds which can make a massive difference!).

I guess ideally it would show a large map of Europe, then each major route colour coded by duration (say green for a 1 hour trip through to red for a 10hr trip). I'm only interested in major cities.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the asker is specifically asking for a map

Comment: My bad, TL;DR here too. No way to unmerge unfortunately.